# Why can’t we override a val property as a var with a get without initialising it?

Tags: jvm, kotlin

I have just started to Learn Kotlin. I wonder why we are not able to use a `get()` method on a overridden val property as a var without initialising it. But when overridden as a `val` it works without initialisation.

```
open class Foo {
    val y = 21
    open val x: Int
        get() {
            return 10 * y
        }
}
class Bar : Foo() {
    override var x: Int = super.x * 10 //If overridden as val works without initialisation
        get() {
            return super.x * (super.x * 10)
        }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val bar: Bar = Bar()
    println("${bar.x}")
}
```

If I don't initialise `x` in `Bar` class it gives a compiler error `Property must be initialised`. But when I print `bar.x` it prints the value calculated from the overridden getter but not from the initialised one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is due to the concept of [backing fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) in Kotlin. As written in the doc -

> A backing field will be generated for a property if it uses the default implementation of at least one of the accessors, or if a custom accessor references it through the field identifier.

Since the overridden property `x` is now a var, it has a default implementation of the setter like below.

```
override var x: Int = super.x * 10 
        get() {
            return super.x * (super.x * 10)
        }
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
```

Therefore when declaring a var, you must initialize the backing field with some value as there is no concept of default values in Kotlin(For e.g. uninitialized Java objects take a null value).

Another solution is to use a custom setter like this -

```
override var x: Int // Now you can leave it uninitialized
            get() {
                return super.x * (super.x * 10)
            }
            set(value) {
                // Nothing happens
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. Well if I do `field = value ` or meddle with `x` in the `set()` it ends up in a StackOverflowError any idea why?

Comment: `field = value` should cause no problem. A possible way to get a StackOverflowError is assigning to `x` in the setter. For e.g.  `x = 0` in `set(value)` will itself recursively call the setter of `x` with `value = 0` and this will end up in an infinite recursion.

Comment: Okay. `field = value` doesn't work as the compiler throws an error as `Property should be initialised`

Comment: `field = value` is what you get by default, so you get the same error.

Comment: Exactly, if you use a backing field, you have to initialize the property whether or not it's immutable.

Comment: @Deepak, `field = value` requires the property to have a backing field, so you should have an initializer for that field as well (`var x: Int = ...`).

Comment: @Deepak, to simply forward the setter call to the super class implementation, use `super.x` (`set(value) { super.x = ... }`)

Comment: @hotkey `super.x` is actually immutable.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot define a `var` property without both accessors (`get` and `set`) defined in some way.

When you put an initializer (`var x: Int = ...`), a backing field is generated and a default setter that sets the backing field. An alternative to the initializer is providing a custom setter:

```
override var x: Int
    get() = super.x * (super.x * 10)
    set(value) { super.x = sqrt(value / 10.0).roundToInt() }
```

See: [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields) in the language reference

Answer (score 0):

```
open class Parent {
    open var x: Int = 0
}

class Child : Parent() {
    override val x = 2
}
```

convert to java

```
public class Parent {
   private int x;

   public int getX() {
      return this.x;
   }

   public void setX(int var1) {
      this.x = var1;
   }
}

public final class Child extends Parent {
   private final int x = 2;

   public int getX() {
      return this.x;
   }
}
```

so
val property did not create setter